# Stanford CoreNLP as a web service

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am working on coreference resolution task, and I want to use the Stanford CoreNLp, but I need it as a  web service, by sending it the sentences and it will retrieve the sentences with resolved anaphora.
I found this page on the Stanford website
[Online Demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process)

So, anyone knows a service to do that, or how can I benefit this website
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below framework,
https://github.com/EducationalTestingService/stanford-thrift

or

https://github.com/nlohmann/StanfordCoreNLPXMLServer

Answer (score 0):

> We use a tomcat servlet built in .jsp to serve parse requests.  This has the benefits that it supports "restful" and that it interfaces
>   very easily with our java code.

https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/parser-user/2011-March/000954.html

This is from John Bauer at stanford talking about the parser part of their products, but probably applies to the coreNLP too.

Not in a terrific amout of detail, but that should get you pointed in the right direction.

There is also a comment here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#cc

> With a bit of work, we're sure you can adapt that example to work in a
>   REST, SOAP, AJAX, or whatever system. If not, pay us a lot of money,
>   and we'll work it out for you. Or if you don't want to do that, maybe
>   look at [what Hat Doang did](https://github.com/dat/stanford-ner). An adaptation of that code now runs
>   our [online demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/).